# error in setupnode events in data driven testing excel in cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-task

[image: my code in config file][![my code in config file][2]][2]

this is my error message

> cy.task('parseXlsx') failed with the following error:
>
> The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method. You must register it before using cy.task()
>
> Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here:

this is my code in cypress.config.js , i have attached image of my code

how can solve this?

Comment: Could you please add details of the `./cypress/plugins/index.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have some legacy plugins coming from `require(/cypress/plugins/index.js)`, which happens when someone has upgraded a project from Cypress v9 to Cypress v10 or higher.

Cypress changed the format of the configuration at v10, but generally that   `require()` should still work the way it is.

But if by mistake `/cypress/plugins/index.js` has now been deleted, you will fail because tasks from it are not available.

It is better to migrate the task code into the new plugins section of `cypress.config.js`, in the future you can modify and debug them more easily.

**Example task in Cypress v10+ configuration**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx').default;
const fs = require('fs'); 
const path = require('path'); 

function parseXlsx({ filePath }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const jsonData = xlsx.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
        resolve(jsonData);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        parseXlsx
      })
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: Can you provide steps to achieve this? how u handles in test files also?any github examples?

Comment: Which parts of the answer are not clear to you, I will try to explain further.

Comment: The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method. You must register it before using cy.task() .This is the error am facing.  But i have given the same code which u have provided.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can figure out what is wrong. There might be some small syntax error.

Comment: No, sorry I tried it and there was no problem in the code, no error occurs. I wonder if there is something needs adjusting in your project structure?

Comment: Can i get an example of full folder structure in cypress? am using version 11. Can u share any links?

Comment: Do u have project with this excel configuration?If so, i can have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255468/discussion-between-anagha-premkumar-and-aladin-spaz).

Comment: I only follow standard documented structure. I suggest you start a clean project, and add a simple task as shown on the documentation page (not xls task, but just the log example given). That way you have a baseline to check on your own machine.

Comment: The problem as I see it is not xls but the fact you task is not seen by test - therefore, simplify the situation first then add in the xls once you have tasks working.

Comment: I have one more doubt. When am importing all files in a specific file and when trying to run, the data is not reading

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to say here.

Comment: issue was in setup nodes and now its cleared.

Comment: i am importing every files in an order in other cy file to run together. but there an issue for data reading from excel . no issues when am running every single file. but when importing and running data is not reading properly